# Can I create a batch program that extracts only one of several IP?

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, findstr, ipconfig

I am trying to create a batch file that port forwards my IP. The IP can be found with the command `ipconfig | findstr IPv4`, but there are multiple internet adapters and multiple IP addresses. I want to get only one address like `192.168.40.??`

192.168.56.1 and 192.168.56.2 is my VirtualBox adapter. I'm not sure how to set the condition in the if statement.

This is the Windows batch file (*.bat):

### ipconfig, findstr:

```
D:\>ipconfig | findstr IPv4
   IPv4 adress . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.2
   IPv4 adress . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   IPv4 adress . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.40.19
```

I tried the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr IPv4`) do (
  for /f delims^=^:^ tokens^=2 %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%c in ("%%b") do (
      set _o1=%%c
      set _o2=%%d
      set _o3=%%e
      set _o4=%%f
      set _4octet=!_o1:~1!.!_o2!.!_o3!.!_o4!     
      echo ==start port fowarding==
      netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 listenaddress=!_4octet! connectport=8080 connectaddress=192.168.56.1
      echo ========================
      netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4
     )
    )
  )
endlocal
```

But this runs on all of my adapters:

```
address         port        address         port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
192.168.56.2    8080        192.168.56.1    8080          <- not want   
192.168.56.1    8080        192.168.56.1    8080          <- not want
192.168.40.19   8080        192.168.56.1    8080          <- i want only
```

I then tried:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr IPv4`) do (
  for /f delims^=^:^ tokens^=2 %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%c in ("%%b") do (
      set _o1=%%c
      set _o2=%%d
      set _o3=%%e
      set _o4=%%f
      set _4octet=!_o1:~1!.!_o2!.!_o3!.!_o4!     
      echo ==start port fowarding==
      if !_4octet!==192.168.56.1
      (
      )
      else if !_4octet!==192.168.56.2
      (
      )
      else
      netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 listenaddress=!_4octet! connectport=8080 connectaddress=192.168.56.1
      echo ========================
      netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4
     )
    )
  )
endlocal
```

But I receive the error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Perhaps the cause is that the variable (!_4octet!) Is not working properly.

```
  if !_4octet! == 192.168.56.1 (
```

Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get something like this ip `192.168.40.*`

You can use a little regex with the command `findstr` like this :

```
ipconfig | findstr IPv4 | findstr /r /c:"192.168.40.*"
```

You can see more help here [findstr /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

> /R /C:string  Use string as a regular expression.

So, with a batch script you can do it to set your IP into Variable like this :

```bat
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr IPv4 ^| findstr /r /c:"192.168.40.*"`) do (
    Set "MyIP=%%a"
    Set "MyIP=!MyIP!"
    set "MyIP=!MyIP: =!" 
)
echo MyIP="!MyIP!"
pause
```

Comment: @jibak How does accepting an answer work?
Welcome on Stack Overflow.
Please take Stack Overflow (SO) [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to say thanks on SO by accepting an answer on being helpful by clicking on gray check mark symbol left to an answer.
See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)
A question with no accepted answer is rated as a not answered question even if there are good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) to retrieve the IP Address:

```bat
@Set "IPA="&For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%A In ('^""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe"^
 NICConfig Where "IPEnabled='TRUE' And Not Description Like '%%VirtualBox%%'"^
 Get IPAddress 2^>NUL^"')Do @Set "IPA=%%A"
@If Defined IPA Echo=%IPA%&Pause>NUL
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.  Thank you for teaching me new knowledge.